# Convert js function to python functions does't work

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, base64, swap

I have found an algorithm written in js (That I don't know how to code with) then I tried to convert it to python after a conversation with some friends who know js
**Javascript**

```js
function crack(code) {
 var N = '';
 var M = '';
 
 for(var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
  if(i%2 == 0) {
   N += code[i];
  } else {
   M = code[i] + M;
  }
 }
 
 var key = N + M;

 key = window.atob(key);
 key = key.substring(2);
 
 return key;
}
```

**Python**

```
import base64
def crack(code):
    N = ''
    M = ''
    i = 0
    for letter in code:
        i =code.find(letter)
        if i%2 == 0:
            N += code[i]
        else:
            M =code[i] + M
    key = N + M
    key = base64.b64decode(key)
    key = key[2:]
    print key
```

As you can see it's the same code but the problem here that not give the same result !! 
The string here to try on is:

> N=m=NAobdtHRRHwaOuiU8mvcZhWddH5bZhz1MWzLapyR5nibbhG19ynccl3RBXvediCV5mjcbh2d0HubZhW1cWvLM4j8ACxONwi8

After searching for a while about window.atob found this method decodes a string of data which has been encoded by the btoa() method.
Then searched about btoa found this method uses the "A-Z", "a-z", "0-9", "+", "/" and "=" characters to encode the string.
Now what to do to get the same result with python ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the first occurrence of letter in the code, in the line `i =code.find(letter)`. As you want the index, I recommend using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Result:

```py
import base64
def crack(code):
    N = ''
    M = ''
    i = 0
    for i, letter in enumerate(code):
        if i%2 == 0:
            N += code[i]
        else:
            M =code[i] + M
    key = N + M
    key = base64.b64decode(key)
    key = key[2:]
    print key
```

Seems correct:

```py
>>> crack('N=m=NAobdtHRRHwaOuiU8mvcZhWddH5bZhz1MWzLapyR5nibbhG19ynccl3RBXvediCV5mjcbh2d0HubZhW1cWvLM4j8ACxONwi8')
http://egyg33k.blogspot.com.eg/2016/08/8-malwarebytes-anti-malware.html
```

Comment: Thank you very much,that's is the answer :D

Comment: @D4Vinci if this answer solves your problem, feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark below the voting arrows. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not the same code.

```
for(var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    if(i%2 == 0) {
```

is NOT the same as

```
for letter in code:
    i =code.find(letter)
    if i%2 == 0:
```

What happens if all letters in the code is the same?

I didn't look further than this.

I recommend doing a "literal" translation first, and THEN attempting a "Pythonic" modification to the code.